# Autoclicker using C++ to click in differnent intervals using RNG * Milliseconds to determine the time between clicks

Tags: c++, random, click

I've been testing it for hours now and I just can't get it to work. 
I'm trying to get an Autoclicker to work, using C++.
Said Program should be able to click without moving the mouse, not specified in the Programm.
The mouse only needs to left-click. 
This has to be done in different intervals. My idea was, that we use a Random Number Generator (RNG) to determine a Number between 1 and 100. 
This step is easy just using a (rand() % 6) + 1 command. 
Loading the  library you can use the command srand(time(0)) before the for function to actually randomize it.
My problem lies after that. 
How to I get the resulting random number to be multiplied by Milliseconds (preferably also randomized) and then use the resulting time as the time beween mouse outputs?

I know this is much to ask but I'm pretty new to coding and this is a passion project. If anyone would be experienced enough to help me out with my problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is what I have so far, I know it's not much but it works. Improvements are obviously welcome though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

/* function main begins program execution */
int main(void) {
    int i; 
    srand(time(0));   
    for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

        printf("%d ", 1 + (rand() % 6));    
    } 

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```